# HttpClient Post getting "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" as response

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have a windows form client that using HttpClient to post an xml (mortgage loan data) to the server and will get a OK response if they created a loan file on the server side.

If works well (so far around 40k content) until I have a slightly bigger request post using httpclient (about 300k content). The request was sent successfully and I confirmed the server side also created the loan file successfully. However, I got the following error in the inner exception:

Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I can't even see the status code of the response.

However, if I capture the content and use postman to post the data. It is working (status 200) and I can get the complete response.

Any idea? I am willing to post my code but they are very formal standard of using HttpClient SendAsync call.

Comment: Can you split file into segments to handle large files?

Comment: 300k content is not big.. is it?

Comment: Maybe check maximum message sizes in your configs-- client, server, and any proxies in between.

Comment: I don't think I can split the file as I have no control on the server side. And @vendettamit, you are right , it is just not that big of a file. I am quite confused and doubt that may be something within the posting content is the cause? Is it even possible? (as the api was called and even the job is done, why it is still throwing me error? ) Any information can help me to learn more about this is apprecaited...